# How to extract a series of data based on specific keys that multiple dicts in a list (PYTHON)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Requirements are:

1. For each record of the file, there should be six main matrices: date, url, title, lang, jsonld,
   metatags. In the metatags, you can find keys and values. **Please extract the data that
   contains any of the keys in the key_list.**

**matrix = ['date', 'url', 'title', 'lang', 'jsonld', 'metatags']**

**key_list = ['description', 'og:description','twitter:description', 'article:tag', 'sailthru.description','parsely-tags',
'abstract', 'og:title']**

**The key is inside the 'metatags'**

The data looks like this (opens with json.loads):

[sample 1 The data looks like this containing 'date', 'url', 'title', 'lang', 'jsonld', 'metatags'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZACF1.png)

[sample 2 The data looks like this containing 'date', 'url', 'title', 'lang', 'jsonld', 'metatags'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiCBO.png)

[sample 3 The data looks like this containing 'date', 'url', 'title', 'lang', 'jsonld', 'metatags'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81oTV.png)

2. Based on the dataset generated from above, **extract the values of the corresponding
   keys in the key list** and **filter out the data that contain any mentions of
   companies in the company_list**. **Generate sentiments for each article
   based on metatags.**

Company list:
['Facebook', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Starbucks', 'McDonald's', 'Walmart', 'Tencent', 'Dutch Shell', 'Volkswagen', 'Apple']

```
#I have tried several ways: 

for key_list in range(len(data0)):
    for matrix in data0[i].items():
        print(matrix)

#or 

next(item for item in data0 if item.get(matrix) and item['metatags'] in key_list)
#Error: StopIteration

#or 

def search(key, data0):
    return [element for element in data0 if data0['key'] in key_list]
```

All doesn't work.
Could anyone gives some help on these 2 requirements, please?

Really want to figure out how to reach these 2 requirements.
They need to be achieved by PYTHON

Comment: That sounds like a homework problem to me. Those are not usually answered here. Try to show where you are stuck and what went wrong not copy paste your homework, IMHO

Comment: Ask about one problem at a time. Post data as text, not as images. Explain what you mean by "All doesn't work". Please read [mcve].

Comment: reply Buggy: Hi, Buggy, I got stck at the very first beginning, i tried generator and wrote a for-loop to do the data filtering, it didn't work, like what i showed above, both questions have tries and Google, but it didn't work well, that's why i asked here.

Comment: reply mzjn: Hi mzjn, well, i want to post it as a pic showing above, but i don't have enough reputation, seems the rule changed, so sorry man, the community turns it to links : (

Comment: "i want to post it as a pic" - Do not post pictures, post plain text!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, try to understand the data structure you are working with.

In your attempts, it seems you are struggling with obtaining the `record` dictionaries, so try to get to those first (currently, 90% of your question focusses on obtaining data from metatags of specific records, filtered on specific keys and further filtered on specific companies, all steps to solve later on).

What is the `data0` variable that you use in your code? Based on the samples you provided, I'll assume it is a list with the `record` dictionaries as entries. In that case, can't you just loop over it like this?

```
for record in data0:
   do work on the record dictionary
```

The further work to do on each `record` dictionary would be something like this:

1. Get the list `metatags` inside your `record` dictionary
2. Loop over each dictionary in your `metatags` list
3. If the `key` entry is in `key_list`, store it in some data structure (up to you to decide what would work best for you) together with the `value` entry

Once you have all this data, I guess you have to loop over all entries you gathered and look at which `value` entries contain one of the companies you provided.

In order to not solve your homework, I think it is best that you focus on getting the records and try implementing the further steps yourself. It is better to come back if you deal with a specific issue (ie: a specific step in your problem) instead of posting the complete question. If my assumption about `data0` is wrong, then please clarify.